# Is there a way to comment code in Notepad2?

Tags: html, xml, comments

Notepad2 is by far my most favorite editor to do quick edits to HTML, XML, etc...

One thing that would be absolutely awesome is the ability to highlight a chunk of XML and comment it out or uncomment it.

Is this possible with Notepad2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> - [release notes](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/doc/Notepad2.txt)

Comment: Control+Shift+Q inserts a DC1 and Control+Q quits the app for some reason.

Comment: I've confirmed that those keyboard combinations work for me (version 4.0.22)

Comment: This command appears to insert C style comments, which doesn't help your XML scenario, anyway.  `Ctrl+Shift+Q` wraps the text in `/*...*/`, `Ctrl+Q` appends `//` to the front of each line.

Comment: Yeah, even though I have the XML scheme as the default, it still places C style comments, which makes it unusable for my scenario.

Comment: yeah i would like to have <!-- -- > instead too as on option